# Nav position:fixed in right of the div

Tags: html, css

I would like to place the nav on the right side of the div dotted with position: fixed. if you use the right: 0 but comes out of the div. how can I do? This is the code:

```
<div style="width:800px; height:2000px; margin:0 auto; border:2px dotted #000;">
  <nav style="position:fixed;">
    <ul>
       <li>voce1</li>
       <li>voce2</li>
       <li>voce3</li>
       <li>voce4</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use position relative. But if you must you position fixed you will need to adjust the right value pending on where that div is on the page. So if the div is 200px from the left then make your right:200px;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position fixed is with respect to the viewport window...so it's not possible to have a fixed div be positioned in relation to another element.

That said, if the 'parent' div has a known width it's possible to play with `calc` to determine the position of the fixed div.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px dotted #000;
}
nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  right: calc(50% - 200px);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>voce1</li>
      <li>voce2</li>
      <li>voce3</li>
      <li>voce4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

This is true even if the div has a percentage width

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  width: 80%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px dotted #000;
}
nav {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  right: calc(50% - 40%);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div style="">
  <nav style="">
    <ul>
      <li>voce1</li>
      <li>voce2</li>
      <li>voce3</li>
      <li>voce4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Note `calc` support is IE9+**

Comment: for internet explorer that is supported only by 9+, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the div in position relative and the nav in position absolute + right 0

```
<div style="width:800px; height:2000px; margin:0 auto; border:2px dotted #000;position: relative;">
  <nav style="position: absolute; right:0">
    <ul>
       <li>voce1</li>
       <li>voce2</li>
       <li>voce3</li>
       <li>voce4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use the fixed because the nav must remain fixed when i scroll the page

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: chrome, firefox and ie 8+ or ie 9+ if there is no possibility to do it

Comment: Have you looked in calc()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: [**EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azQezP)

If so, your code will now be:

```
    <div style="position:relative; width:800px; height:2000px; margin:0 auto; border:2px dotted #000;">
      <nav style="position:absolute; right:0;">
        <ul>
           <li>voce1</li>
           <li>voce2</li>
           <li>voce3</li>
           <li>voce4</li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>*
```

Comment: I need to use the fixed because the nav must remain fixed when i scroll the page